# Adding URL parameters to Google Webmaster Tools: URL encoded or not?

Tags: google-search-console, url

When adding parameters to Webmaster Tools for URLs that I don't want indexed, should I add the parameters with actual brackets, example:

```
technology[above_average]
```

or should add in the URL encoding characters which are showing in the SERPs URL like so:

```
technology%5Babove_average%5D
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googlebot expects URL parameter names to be **escaped** when adding them via Google Webmaster Tools.

I ran an experiment on my site where I created a page with two different URL parameters: `unesc%` and `escap%`.  I created [page for the experiment on my site](http://attesoro.org/experiment.php). On it uses the parameters with four values each

I then added `escap%25` and `unesc%` to Google Webmaster Tools as "Effect: None, Crawl: Representative URL" and sat back to watch what would happen.

The first thing I noticed was that Googlebot actually came to my site and crawled all the parameters, despite the webmaster tools setting.  This is either because:

- There is a bug in Googlebot where it doesn't respect the settings
- They designed Gogolebot not to respect the settings
- It takes some time for Googlebot to become aware of the settings.  (I put the settings in before Googlebot had a chance to crawl, but it started crawling within an hour).

After Googlebot crawled, webmaster tools didn't report that Googlebot was monitoring *any* matching URLs.   I figured that it would take some time before GWT started showing what Googlebot was actually doing so I waited.  A couple weeks later I now get this:

[image]

I would still suggest adding both to your site just as a precaution (I'm only linking to the escaped version of the URL, I'm not user if it would be different if I linked to the un-escaped version).

---

Here is the testing that I had done earlier:

I tested it by adding both, just to see how the tool would react.

[image: Google webmaster tools, url parameters with encoding]

I thought that it might give me an error for one of the two, or possibly canonicalize them to the same thing.  I could actually add both of them (as you can see from the screenshot).

That leads me to guess that the un-escaped one is the one that would match while Googlebot is crawling.  But, that is just a guess.  Since it allows you to add both, you might as well just go ahead and add both to be safe.